# SESSION is empty with AJAX PHP or APACHE misconfiguration issue

Tags: php, ajax, apache, session

I was working on a webpage and it was working all fine until I tried to send it to my paid web hosting service. It is the first time I try to use SESSIONs in this new remote server.

My application stopped working and I thought there was something wrong with the API I use. After a long attempt to fix this problem, I tried to `var_dump()` the SESSION array. It was empty. But only with AJAX requests. If I access it directly via browser it works great, but with AJAX it fails. I turned sessions on with the `session_start()` function.

So I bet it's some problem with my PHP.ini or any configuration in the Apache running on my remote web server.

Do you guys know how to solve it? Can it be a problem with the script I am using to send the requests? It works fine on `localhost`

**@edit**

testing.php

```
session_start();
echo session_id();
$_SESSION['testing'] = 'some_stuff';
```

server.php

```
session_start();
echo session_id();
echo 'testing is '.$_SESSION['testing'];
```

Comment: When doing AJAX request, try to `var_dump(session_id())` what does it return?

Comment: just tried it, don't know what I did, but now all the session_ids are different. i created a test.php that starts and saves an new index in SESSION. and then I try to read it in the script that listens to AJAX requests. the index is not there and the `session_id()` are different

just edit my original post with what I did.

Comment: do you call `session_destroy()` anywhere?

Comment: no. it`s a very simple script. the API I am talking about is the FACEBOOK SDK. i realized it was not keeping my access tokens, I didn`t even know they were saved in session. when I var_dump SESSION, it was empty.

Comment: `session_start()` returns TRUE if a session was successfully started, otherwise FALSE. Therefore it worth nothing to see if it returns true try to `var_dump(session_start())` in both places.

Comment: it says `bool(true)`.